# Arduino LCD displaying odd characters

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm using the LCD dispaly with the soil moisture sensor and it seems using the following returns an odd set of characters on the first line.

```
  LCD.print("Soil Moisture");  //Print Message on First Row
```

Although using the following, works perfectly

```
  LCD.print("Water level");  //Print Message on First Row
```

***Also worth noting, its printing correctly to SerialMonitor***

Being new to learning Arduino, it feels like a bug to me but I can't be sure.

The whole code is as follows:

```
// This sketch will use the soil moisture sensor and display the result on the LCD

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
// include the LCD library
LiquidCrystal LCD(10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4);
// Set pins as 10,9,7,6,5,4. It might be different for your LCD, check the producer catalog

int potPin = A0; //input pin
int soil = 0;
int percent = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  LCD.begin(16,2); //Tell Arduino to start your 16 column 2 row LCD
  LCD.setCursor(0,0);  //Set LCD cursor to upper left corner, column 0, row 0
  LCD.print("Soil Moisture");  //Print Message on First Row
    delay(1000);
}
void loop() {
  // map the values
  int soil = analogRead(potPin) ;
  soil = constrain(soil, 600, 1023);
  soil = map(soil, 600, 1023, 0, 100);

  LCD.setCursor(0,1);
  //display final numbers
  LCD.print(soil);
  //print the percent symbol at the end
  LCD.print("%");
  //wait 0.1 seconds
  delay(75);
  //wipe the extra characters
  LCD.print(" ");

  Serial.print("Water level:");
  Serial.print(soil);
  Serial.println("%");
  delay(1000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is it printing to you exactly?

Comment: Just added a photo to the issue.

Comment: Yeah, weird… I do not see any error in your code, and do not understand why it is working with `LCD.print("Water level");`… Except that there are two capital letters in `"Soil Moisture"` there are no differences between these two `string`. Have you tried to `clear` this display before printing?

Comment: Yep, added the lcd.clear and still remains

Comment: `LiquidCrystal LCD(10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4);` must fit to your wiring. I guess you scrambled the four data lines, else it would not work at all. Try a simple "hello" or other test sketch (E.g. display a single character, changing once a second)